# Cannot build .NET 6 project on mac due to references to .NETFramework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I have a .NET6 Core project (executable) that builds fine on windows computers, even if the target platform is linux. However on Mac, the project cannot build, it gets one of two errors:

`project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETFramework,Version=v6.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net60' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.`

or:

`The reference assemblies for '.NETFramework,Version=v6.0' were not found.`

As far as I can tell, I do not use the .NETFramework, only .NET Core.

In addition, in my .csproj file I have the following entry at the top:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I am of the understanding that .NETFramework and .NET 6 are similar but not the same.  I cannot figure out why we have the .NETFramework as a target at all or how to remove this.  I get this error whether I set as executable or library.  How can I remove this dependency?

What else could be causing this issue?

Comment: You are building this with a .NET SDK that doesn't yet know about .net6.  You need to update it.

Comment: This is weird. You are right: **there's no such thing** as `.NETFramework,Version=v6.0`. Framework stops at version 4.8 (right now). 5.0 and greater is .Net Core, and that's _not Framework_ anymore.

Comment: Also, IIRC, when it says to include `net60` as a TargetFramework, it means `net60`, and **not** `net6.0`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: The following may be of interest: [Target frameworks in SDK-style projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) also see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-a-target-framework).

Comment: How have you created this project? If using Visual Studio, .NET 6 requires Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: @user09938 I'm using the latest visual studio for mac. I did not create this project I'm trying to maintain it.

Comment: @HansPassant the only dotnet installed on this machine is .NET 6 and .NET 7.  These are the only sdks and verified with `dotnet --list-sdks`:

6.0.308 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.404 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.405 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

Comment: That does look okay, now what.  Ultimately it is an msbuild problem, do make sure you don't run an old version of it.  Type just plain msbuild to see the version number.  Try targeting .net7, blindly reinstalling the SDKs with crossed fingers is worth a try.

Comment: Check NuGet Package Manager settings (Tools => Options => NuGet Package Manager => General => Default package management format). It should be set to `PackageReference`.